# How to deserialize tree of object and perform some action on each node with Jackson

Tags: jackson, deserialization, interceptor

I have a tree of objects in json format (they have one ancestor).

I need to deserialize and for each node of object node of tree perform some action. (after deserialization i need to have a list of names of all objects in tree).

I tried to write custom deserializer for it and annotate abstract parent of all those class

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
public abstract class AGuidelineElementBase {
```

and

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = Guideline.class)
public class Guideline extends AGuidelineElementBase implements Serializable {
```

for each subclass.
but i get stackOverFlow

Please tell me how can i add some logic to deserialization of each  TreeNode.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to utilise the [Jackson JSON Interceptor Module](https://github.com/jonpeterson/jackson-module-json-interceptor)